# What is the meaning of $V(D,G)$ in the GAN objective function?

Tags: machine-learning, generative-model, generative-adversarial-networks, notation

Here is [the GAN objective function](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2014/file/5ca3e9b122f61f8f06494c97b1afccf3-Paper.pdf).

$$\min _{G} \max _{D} V(D, G)=\mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol{x} \sim p_{\text {data }}(\boldsymbol{x})}[\log D(\boldsymbol{x})]+\mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol{z} \sim p_{\boldsymbol{z}}(\boldsymbol{z})}[\log (1-D(G(\boldsymbol{z})))]$$

What is the meaning of $V(D, G)$?

How do we get these expectation parts?

I was trying to understand it following this article: [Understanding Generative Adversarial Networks *(D.Seita)*](https://danieltakeshi.github.io/2017/03/05/understanding-generative-adversarial-networks/), but, after many tries, I still can't understand how he got from $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \log D(x)$ to $\mathbb{E}(\log(D(x))$.

Comment: Your second question is related to [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/23161/2444).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To understand this equation first you need to understand the [context in which it is first introduced](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf). We have two neural networks (i.e. $D$ and $G$) that are playing a minimax game. This means that they have competing goals. Let's look at each one separately:

#### Generator

Before we start, you should note that throughout the whole paper the notion of the [data-generating distribution](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/54349/34269) is used; in short the authors will refer to the samples through their underlying distributions, i.e. if a sample $a$ is drawn from a distribution $p_a$, we'll denote this as $a \sim p_a$. Another way to look at this is that $a$ *follows* distribution $p_a$.

The generator ($G$) is a neural network that produces samples from a distribution $p_g$. It is trained so that it can bring $p_g$ as close to $p_{data}$ as possible so that samples from $p_g$ become indistinguishable to samples from $p_{data}$. The catch is that it never gets to actually see $p_{data}$. Its inputs are samples $z$ from a noise distribution $p_z$.

#### Discriminator

The discriminator ($D$) is a simple binary classifier that tries to identify which class a sample $x$ belongs to. There are two possible classes, which we'll refer to as the *fake* and the *real*. Their respective distributions are $p_{data}$ for the *real* samples and $p_g$ for the *fake* ones (note that $p_g$ is actually the distribution of the outputs of the generator, but we'll get back to this later).

Since it is a simple binary classification task, the discriminator is trained on a binary cross-entropy error:

$$
J^{(D)} = H(y, \hat y) = H(y, D(x))
$$

where $H$ is the cross-entropy $x$ is sampled either from $p_{data}$ or from $p_g$ with a probability of $50\%$. More formally:

$$
x \sim
\begin{cases}
p_{data} \rightarrow & y = 1, & \text{with prob 0.5}\\
p_g \;\;\;\,\rightarrow & y = 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

We consider $y$ to be $1$ if $x$ is sampled from the *real* distribution and $0$ if it is sampled from the *fake* one. Finally, $D(x)$ represents the probability with which $D$ thinks that $x$ belongs to $p_{data}$. By writing the cross-entropy formula we get:

$$
H(y, D(x)) = \mathbb{E}_y[-log \; D(x)] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}{ \; y_i \; log(D(x_i))}
$$

where $N$ is the size of the dataset. Since each class has $N/2$ samples we can split this sum into two parts:
$$
= - \left[ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N/2}{ \; y_i \; log(D(x_i))} +  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=N/2}^{N} \; (1 - y_i) \; log((1 - D(x_i))) \right]
$$

The first of the two terms represents the the samples from the $p_{data}$ distribution, while the second one the samples from the $p_g$ distribution. Since all $y_i$ are equally likely to occur, we can convert the sums into expectations:

$$
= - \left[ \frac{1}{2} \; \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}}[log \; D(x)] + \frac{1}{2} \; \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{g}}[log \; (1 - D(x))] \right]
$$

At this point, we'll ignore $2$ from the equations since it's constant and thus irrelevant when optimizing this equation. Now, remember that samples that were drawn from $p_g$ were actually outputs from the generator (obviously this affects only the second term). If we substitute $D(x), x \sim p_g$ with $D(G(z)), z \sim p_z$ we'll get:

$$
L_D = - \left[\; \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}}[log \; D(x)] + \; \mathbb{E}_{z \sim p_{z}}[log \; (1 - D(G(z)))] \right]
$$

This is the final form of the discriminator loss.

#### Zero-sum game setting

The discriminator's goal, through training, is to minimize its loss $L_D$. Equivalently, we can think of it as trying to maximize the opposite of the loss:

$$
\max_D{[-J^{(D)}]} = \max_D \left[\; \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}}[log \; D(x)] + \; \mathbb{E}_{z \sim p_{z}}[log \; (1 - D(G(z)))] \right]
$$

The generator however, wants to maximize the discriminator's uncertainty (i.e. $J^{(D)}$), or equivalently minimize $-J^{(D)}$.

$$
J^{(G)} = - J^{(D)}
$$

Because the two are tied, we can summarize the whole game through a **value function** $V(D, G) = -J^{(D)}$. At this point I like to think of it like we are seeing the whole game through the eyes of the generator. Knowing that $D$ tries to maximize the aforementioned quantity, the goal of $G$ is:

$$
\min_G\max_D{V(D, G)} = \min_G\max_D \left[\; \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_{data}}[log \; D(x)] + \; \mathbb{E}_{z \sim p_{z}}[log \; (1 - D(G(z)))] \right]
$$

#### Disclaimer:

This whole endeavor (on both my part and the authors' part) was to provide a mathematical formulation to training GANs. In practice there are many tricks that are invoked to effectively train a GAN, that are not depicted in the above equations.